# Is there a named distribution with the property $P(X>10^k) = p^k$?

Tags: distributions, power-law, pareto-distribution

If I'm doing my math correctly, the exponential distribution has the property $P(X >k) = p ^ k$ (with $p$ conventionally written as $e ^ {-\lambda}$). I'm wondering if there is a different distribution with the property $P(X>10^k) = p^k$? (Or more broadly $P(X>n^k) = p^k$ for some parameters $p, n$.)

Comment: Yes, power-law distributions have this property.

Comment: You can reparameterize this to $$P(X > x) = x^{log_n(p)}$$